# Does small capacity of a set imply that its measure is small too?

Tags: analysis, potential-theory

I would like to know if an open set with small capacity also has small measure. To be more specific, I would like to know if the following statement is true:

For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain (i.e., open and connected)  with $\text{Cap}_p(\Omega) < \delta$, then $|\Omega| < \epsilon$.

Here $1<p<n$, and $\text{Cap}_p(\Omega)$ is the $p$-capacity of the set $\Omega$, i.e., 
\begin{equation*}
\text{Cap}_p (\Omega) = \inf\left\{ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla u|^p\,dx : u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n), u = 1 \text{ on }\Omega  \right\}. 
\end{equation*} 
Also $|\Omega|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\Omega$.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that this definition is correct? Because if $u = 1$ on the open set $\Omega$, then $u$ is a constant there and its weak derivative $\nabla u$ will vanish over the whole domain that you're integrating over, right? So your capacity would always be zero. You probably need to modify this definition a bit.

Comment: Thanks Lukas there was a typo on the domain of integration